# Function pointer declaration syntax confusion

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, function-pointers

I have read and googled about the right-left rule to decode function pointers.

For ex:

```
int (*(*fun_one)(char *,double))[9][20];
```

is: **fun_one is pointer to function expecting (char *,double) and 
      returning pointer to array (size 9) of array (size 20) of int.**

So what is

```
const char code[] = "\x31\xc0";

int main(){
     ((void(*)( ))code)();
}
```

"**code is ?? returning a pointer to function returning void...???? what about after that the outside ()**"

I am utterly confused with this one.

Comment: What do you mean by *frame*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const char code[] = "\x31\xc0";

int main(){
     ((void(*)( ))code)();
}
```

Here's how it works. The `code` variable will decay to the address of the first element (`\x31`).

That address will then be cast to the address of a function taking indeterminate arguments, and returning nothing.

That covers the entire `((void(*)( ))code)` bit and, up to there, you've basically constructed a function pointer pointing to your string.

The `()` then simply *calls* the function that you're pointing to.

If that's an Intel CPU you're targeting, `31 c0` disassembles to `xor eax, eax` but I'm not expecting much joy when it runs off the end of the buffer, it's likely to crash spectacularly. The `\x00` marking the end of the string is the first bit of an `add` instruction but, as to what comes after that, there's no guarantee.

Adding a `ret` instruction to the end of the string *may* make it safer but you may have to examine the generated assembler code for the call itself to figure out *which* `ret` should be used.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a function pointer *declaration*, it's a function pointer *cast* and a *call*.

Glossing over the cast for a moment, we have `((`sometype`)code)()` — that is, cast `code` to some type (obviously a function pointer) and then call it.

So what's the type inside the cast? It's `void (*)()`. In other words, a pointer to a function that returns `void` and takes nothing in particular (it actually *can* take arguments, thanks to C legacy, but in this case it doesn't). Nothing in, nothing out.

After the `*` is where the name would go if this was a declaration, but since it's a cast, the type stands alone and there's no name at all.

Answer (score 2):

You are confused because it's not a function pointer declaration, but a cast followed by a function call.

```
(void (*)()) code
```

This casts `code` to a pointer to a function taking an unspecified number of arguments returning nothing.

```
((void (*)()) code)
```

This is the whole expression above enclosed in parentheses; the result is a function pointer.

```
(void (*)() code)();
```

This calls the function to which the function pointer "created" by the cast points.

This is effectively trying to call some machine code constructed in `code` - here you are omitting the rest, but 31 c0 is the usual `xor eax,eax`.

Comment: wow you not only explained but even decoded the hex dump code. That is awesome. Thanks !